# Google Tag Manager giving mixed content error

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, ssl, https, google-tag-manager

I'm in the process of converting our site over to https. This is going well so far, but I can't seem to figure out how to get rid of this console error in Chrome.

[image]

The Google Tag Manager code that appears in the _Layout.cshtml page is pulled straight from [Google](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/quickstart) and looks like this:

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<noscript><iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-XXXX"
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXX');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the Tag Manager itself, it's one the tags contained within - you can see that the error message refers to "http://bs.serving-sys.com/" which is an adserver.

Most probably you have a publisher tag either as custom html tag or as custom image and your publisher redirects his tracking tag to a tag from bs.serving-sys.com without using ssl encryption.

This kind of thing happens not to rarely and annoys the heck out of me ( I work in an online marketing company) because it makes impossible to tell who receives user data from my clients webpages (which creates interesting legal questions, too). And of course having unencrypted elements pretty much breaks ssl.

You should go to the network tab of your browser and look for redirects (302 most probably) to see which of your tags initiates the redirect.